# Automatically set gcloud quota project to the current project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have two `gcloud` configurations for two different projects with their own kubernetes clusters and switch between them frequently, they use two different gcloud projects. This seems like a normal setup and worked fine up until maybe a year ago, when I started to receive warning messages about the quota project in my local Application Default Credentials not matching the active project. The billing/quota_project on all my configurations is set to the special value "CURRENT_PROJECT", but the ADC quota project doesn't accept this value.

```bash
# quota project is set to first_config's project
> gcloud config configurations activate second_config
Activated [second_config].
WARNING: Your active project does not match the quota project in your local Application Default Credentials file. This might result in unexpected quota issues.

To update your Application Default Credentials quota project, use the `gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project` command.
> gcloud config get billing/quota_project
Your active configuration is: [second_config]
CURRENT_PROJECT
> gcloud auth application-default set-quota-project CURRENT_PROJECT
ERROR: (gcloud.auth.application-default.set-quota-project) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Request contains an invalid argument.
```

Is there a way to set the *ADC quota project* to the current project automatically? I don't want to have to run an additional, slow `gcloud auth` command every time I switch configurations. Is the only option to change the [`GOOGLE_CLOUD_QUOTA_PROJECT`](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota/set-quota-project#set-project-variable) env var to the current project when I change configs? That's less inconvenient, but I feel like I'm missing something, especially since this config switching used to work without the quota project warning.

Comment: Why not just write a script that switches environments? User credentials are intended for developers. For production environments, I recommend switching to service accounts as they do not have API quota project issues.

Comment: I already do use scripts for switching environments, but I still do not want to run an additional `glcoud` command if I don't have to, they tend to be very slow due to the network calls. Prod already does use SAs but sometimes we have to run ad hoc commands against the prod cluster, which requires switching to its context.

Comment: I recommend following the official documentation instead of looking for shortcuts. Your question does include details like which languages/SDKs/libraries you are using or rely upon. The lack of attention to detail by one of those can cause unofficial strategies to break - which happens often. For example, C++ libraries use a different environment variable and C++ is used in many places. In other words, I do not recommend looking for shortcuts and just have more patience.